# Routing web.config to index.php within folder

Tags: windows, iis, web-config, webserver, web.config-transform

I have no experience working with windows web servers so i'm a bit lost. I'd like to setup a folder that routes all urls to index.php. I have attempted a few different configurations without any of them working.

How I would do it in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Software
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

My attempts with web.config:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Redirect To Index" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder/index.php" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the below rules in webconfig file under the Software directory. If the webconfig file doesn't exists, create it.  the rules in it can be recognized by IIS.

```
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IIS rewrite rules are designed with a different philosophy. It doesn’t support the `RewriteBase` command. We just place the `webconfig` file in the corresponding folder. The rest URL rules will work in the specific directory.
In addition, the rest URL rules could be automatically converted into IIS Rewrite Rules by using the below IIS features.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules
About how to convert the `RewriteBase` command.
https://forums.iis.net/t/1162790.aspx
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your configuration out and it seems like it had no effect on on routing. I'll try to explain whats going on a little better. Basically I the webconfig file within the folder "/folder/", rather than the main project folder. When I tried putting your configuration in "/folder/", it still routed based on the main routing rules.

Comment: The relative address relies on the path of the root website and absolute address will depend on the path where the WebConfig locates. Assumed that there are an index.php page under the folder directory and a webconfig file. the URL of rewrite action should be “/folder/index.php” or “index.php”     
Placing the webconfig file under the Software folder represents that the URL Rewrite rules only work in the Software folder.